# How can I save binary Image using C1Upload to the SQL Database?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Is there a way to save image to the database using  C1Upload. I am only using Asp.Net, C#.Net for the programming and Javascript of needed and nothing else. Is there a way in saving without using Silverlight?

Thanks

-Mush

Answer (score 0):

You you do this by reading the bytes of uploaded file in `C1Upload1_Uploaded` event.

```
    protected void C1Upload1_Uploaded(object sender, UploadedFileEventArgs e)
    {
        //Read uploaded file stream
        C1FileInfo file = e.UploadedFile;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Size];
        file.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, file.Size);
        file.GetStream().Close();

        //Save file bytes to database
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("sqlConnectionString");
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSET INTO yourtable(image) VALUES(@image)", sqlConn);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", buffer);
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
```